# system time is different than apache timestamp --?

Tags: php, apache, timezone

Im on a development server. When i do this in php:

```
echo date('r',time());
```

response: **Tue, 01 Jun 2010 18:10:32 -0400**

However, my computer's time is 17:10:32 (im on GMT -5). Where do i configure my apache/php to change this setting? i've looked in php.ini and httpd.conf already.

Thanks

Comment: i already set it up with: 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Guayaquil');

Comment: Perhaps a daylight saving time related problem? Personally I use UTC everywhere, specifically to avoid time zone related hassle.

Comment: Is there any way to make it use systems time and time zone ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit your `php.ini` file and add the following code in the `Date` section

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Guayaquil
```

That will define the timezone for all your php pages.

Answer (score 3):

To set your server's time-zone add a line to your .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv TZ America/Indianapolis
```

For a list of supported timezones:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php